# How to deal with insignificance and multicolinearity?

Tags: regression, self-study, statistical-significance, econometrics, multicollinearity

When performing a regression analysis to test whether Asians have the lowest COVID mortality rates using stata, none of variables seem to have significance other than population. How do I determine which area have the lowest covid mortality rate? How do I fix it? Do I just interpret it as area has no affect?
This is a homework question.
[image]

This regression has passed ovtest, linktest, and hettest. There was a heteroskedasticity issue but it has went away after the y variable was log-transformed. However, there are some multicolonearity issues. If I remove any of the variables to try and solve multicolinearity, ovtest shows that there's omitted variables..How should I get rid of multicolinearity?

[image]

These are the commands I have used in stata,

```
tabulate area, gen(area_dummy)

rename area_dummy1 Africa

rename area_dummy2 Asia

rename area_dummy3 Europe

rename area_dummy4 North_America

rename area_dummy5 Oceania

rename area_dummy6 South_America

replace Oceania=0 if area=="Oceania"

gen gdp_per_capita=0

replace gdp_per_capita=gdp/population

gen ln_mortalityrate = ln(mortalityrate)

reg ln_mortalityrate Asia Africa Europe North_America South_America gdp_per_capita population lifeexpectancy cpi phighschool
```

Data set includes:

```
COUNTRY Country name

REGION      Country region

CASES       Total number of COVID cases thus far in the country

DEATHS      Total number of COVID death thus far in the country 

CPI         Current consumer price index of the country

PHIGHSCHOOL Percent of adults achieved high school education

LIFEEXPECTANCY  Years

GDP     GDP in current year

POPULATION  Number of population

MORTALITY RATE = DEATHS/POPULATION
```