# How to deal with insignificance in this regression?

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, stata, multicollinearity

The hw question:
Data set includes:

```
COUNTRY Country name

REGION      Country region

CASES       Total number of COVID cases thus far in the country

DEATHS      Total number of COVID death thus far in the country 

CPI         Current consumer price index of the country

PHIGHSCHOOL Percent of adults achieved high school education

LIFEEXPECTANCY  Years

GDP     GDP in current year

POPULATION  Number of population

MORTALITY RATE = DEATHS/POPULATION
```

Based on the given data, use a regression analysis to test whether Asians have the lowest COVID mortality rates. Report and interpret the results.

When performing a regression analysis to test whether Asians have the lowest COVID mortality rates using stata, none of variables seem to have significance other than population. (all variables have P value over 0.05) How do I determine which area have the lowest covid mortality rate? How do I fix it? Do I just interpret it as area has no affect and asians doesn't have the lowest mortality rate?

[image]

Extra :
This regression has passed ovtest, linktest, VIF test, and hettest. There was a heteroskedasticity issue but it has went away after the y variable was log-transformed. Multicolinearity goes away when I get rid of Africa or Europe.

These are the commands I have used in stata,

```
tabulate area, gen(area_dummy)

rename area_dummy1 Africa

rename area_dummy2 Asia

rename area_dummy3 Europe

rename area_dummy4 North_America

rename area_dummy5 Oceania

rename area_dummy6 South_America

replace Oceania=0 if area=="Oceania"

gen gdp_per_capita=0

replace gdp_per_capita=gdp/population

gen ln_mortalityrate = ln(mortalityrate)

reg ln_mortalityrate Asia Europe North_America South_America gdp_per_capita population lifeexpectancy cpi phighschool
```

Comment: Can you analyze relative risk or attributable risk directly?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: If this is not for learning about regression analysis, I'd suggest to ask on https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com if your model makes any sense in the first place. Depending on the purpose of the model, you may be omitting important variables (what about age structure, health systems capacity, etc.?), and anyway the number of cases and deaths is probably not reliable to conduct comparisons between countries (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_death_rates_by_country#Data_reliability)

Comment: It seems you have deleted your earlier [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/628804/how-to-deal-with-insignificance-and-multicolinearity) and reposted it. Please refrain from this practice. Read why it was closed and edit it for it to be sent to reopen review queue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was already asked by OP and after it got closed, they deleted it and reposted it altogether.

Comment: It was closed because I needed to add more details. I changed the wording a bit to get my question clearer but it's still kind of the same. I don't know what details I should add more so please advise me on that if possible.

Comment: Although I agree with the closure, I don't think the question is "off-topic". I would have probably chosen "lack of clarity". @JessFranc It may help to read the [self-study wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then if you'd like to work on re-opening your question (don't ask a new one; edit this one instead), I'd suggest to pare it down to one very specific question. For example I'm confused what significance has to do with Asian countries having the lowest mortality. The second table seems to report that both African and European countries have lower mortality.

Comment: I am curious why you think your question is relevant to the prompt you are given: could you articulate why you think issues of significance of ancillary variables would help test whether Asians have the lowest mortality rates?